# The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity" in class does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm getting a well-known error for Doctrine, but nothing seems to work.

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity" in
>   class ac\User\Entity\User does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

My class starts off like this:

```
<?php
namespace ac\User\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
```

My `cli-config.php`

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/Entity"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(

    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

There must be 100 questions out there about this. Doctrine really needs to come to a consensus on this.

Answer (score 0):

What's your symfony version ?

If you works with symfony 4, i suggest you to install theses dependencies:

```
composer require symfony/orm-pack symfony/maker-bundle sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

**sensio/framework-extra-bundle** seems to be necessary to use doctrine annotation like Entity or Table ect.

Comment: It was my Doctrine version.  I had set "minimum-stability": "dev"